# Open native Twitter App from my Application using IBAction

Tags: objective-c, xcode, twitter, ibaction, url-scheme

I'd like to implement the natvie Twitter App into my iOS Application.
I've already done that with Facebook by using the URL Schemes. But I weren't able to find such thing for Twitter.

For Facebook I used:

```
-(IBAction)facebook:(id)sender {
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://"]];
}
```

But when I try to use

```
@"Twitter" or @"twitter" or @"tw"
```

nothing happens.
Would be great if you guys could help me out. I haven't found anything in the Interweb :/
If there is something just like it please :)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Nathans solution below will work, but I have to ask are you trying this on the simulator? It will only work on a real device with the twitter app installed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Did you try:

```
twitter://
```

ex:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://user?screen_name=username"]];
```

Comment: Yeah i've got I working by now :)

Still thank you. It was just a spelling error I didn't saw -.-

Comment: Haha thanks :p
Asking in a forum because of a spelling failure is kinda the most stupid thing one could do -.-

Comment: how can i check twitter is exist on phone ? @NathanSakoetoe